# Cannot change ownership of host directory mounted with docker-machine on MAC

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I was running docker-machine using vboxsf on my mac, when I run the following command

```
docker run \
    -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes 
    -P
    -v $(pwd)/data:/var/lib/mysql
    mysql:5.6
```

It fails to mount the volume with correct permission, so no data can be written to the directory

Then I use docker-machine-nfs to mount /Users, then the command returns

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
```

Did I miss something?